# How can we inherit inner classes

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I am trying the following but give me compile time error

```
   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        shape.innershape s = new rectangle(); // Error Here

    }
}
class shape
{
    public int nshape = 0;
    public shape()
    {
        nshape = 1;
        innershape n = new innershape();
    }
    public void MakeOuterShape()
    {

    }
    public class innershape
    {
        public int nInnerShape = 0;
        public innershape()
        {
            nInnerShape = 1;
        }
        public void makeInnerShape()
        {

        }
    }
}
class rectangle :shape
{
     // Code goes here.
}
```

I am inheriting `Shape` class which contains the definition of `innershape` class. But when i try to make instance of `Rectangle` class with reference to `innershape` shows me compile time error. Why ?? and how can make it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inner classes in C# are not like Java inner classes, they do not belong to the outer class, it is just a matter of visibility.

You have to derive Rectangle from `shape.innershape`.

Answer (score 1):

since *rectangle* is inherired from *shape*, but not from *innershape*

```
  class rectangle: shape {
  ...

  public class innershape
  {
   ...
```

you can't write

```
shape.innershape s = new rectangle(); // <- can't convert rectangle to shape
```

But you can put instead

```
  shape s = new rectangle(); // shape is super class for rectangle
```

Perharps you should change your code into

```
  class rectangle :shape.innershape 
  {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try making your classes public, that way visibility won't be limited.